# iOS10 Safari Keyboard Popup

Tags: safari, keyboard, ios10

I have a single page web app. The keyboard pops-up everytime I click on the screen.

There are no text input boxes in the DOM at all.

How can I debug why the keyboard is popping up.

You can see examples of this strange behaviour at https://blight.ironhelmet.com and https://np.ironhelmet.com

---

update with a clue: A user is now reporting that rather than the keyboard, a dropdown selection spiner is popping up all the time, long after that dropdown has been removed from the DOM.

Comment: Can you post some code and the link of the webpage to better understand the scenario?

Comment: I see the same thing with a React site. If the keyboard is showing, and the user closes the dialog (removing the input boxes from the DOM), then the keyboard constantly pops up every time I do anything.

Answer (score 3):

### For React users:

I had the same thing happen in a React single-page app with React-Router. I didn't write code to remove elements from the DOM, but of course React does that for you.

On my site, there are React components that contain one to four input fields. After any such component appears, and then is hidden (unmounted / not rendered anymore), then any time the user taps a link, the keyboard pops up. This makes the site unusable. The only way to make it stop was to reload the page.

The workaround: calling `document.activeElement.blur()` in `componentWillUnmount` **for the wrapper component around my `<input>` fields** did the trick.

```
componentWillUnmount()
{
  if (document && document.activeElement)
  {
    document.activeElement.blur();
  }
}
```

Note that calling window.activeElement.blur() did not seem to do anything.

There's a thread in the Apple support forums about this issue:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7692319

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the keyboard was holding a reference to input after I had removed them from the DOM.

I added a test when removing element to see if it was the current activeElement, then, if so, calling document.activeElement.blur() before removing it. Seems to have solved the problem so far.